# Is there free analog for Varnish High Availability (nginx, haproxy, varnish config for HA)?

Tags: nginx, varnish, haproxy

Is there free analog for Varnish High Availability (nginx, haproxy, varnish config for HA)?
Which architecture is better for HA VoD cluster: nginx + memcached, haproxy + varnish, nginx + varnish?
Read several articles with different solutions. And everybody thinks different:

1. Some say that nginx as a load balancer is not the best solution: nginx - 7 parameters for tracking against haproxy - 65 parameters for tracking (+ status of backends)
2. Others suggest implementing the scheme Haproxy + Varnish
3. The third offer to organize Nginx + Memcache (as a caching server with an emphasis on the fact that varnish does not know how to work with ssl, nginx is self-contained in this respect and there is a negative experience of using nginx + varnish - they say that bugs are not caught correctly and "double" caching does not justify yourself)

---

1. Which scheme is the most justified and best of all recommended for high quality VoD (720p, 1080p)?
2. What to put on the front as a caching proxy?
3. What should I put on the backend in the cache?

Comment: PS: need architecture with cache replication like in Varnish  High Availability  scheme

Comment: https://preview.ibb.co/hNiEiT/Screenshot_20180612_090729.png

Comment: You may want to stop reading and start testing.  Opinions are everywhere, but all of the mentioned products work correctly for their designed purposes (as well as for many purposes for which they were not designed).  I'm voting to close the question as off-topic, as the question is essentially seeking product recommendations and design suggestions... and there is no objectively "correct" answer.

Comment: @gremlintv2 although marked offtopic - did you search yield any results?